# Regex to match all words but the one beginning and ending with special chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling with a regex for Javascript.

Here is a string from which I want to match all words but the one prefixed by \+\s and suffixed by \s\+ :

> this-is my + crappy + example

The regex should match :

> **this-is** **my** + crappy + **example**

match 1: this-is

match 2: my

match 3: example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left, ( *saying throw this away, it's garbage* ) and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right side.

```
\+[^+]+\+|([\w-]+)
```

**Example**:

```
var re = /\+[^+]+\+|([\w-]+)/g,
    s  = "this-is my + crappy + example",
    match,
    results = [];

while (match = re.exec(s)) {
   results.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(results.filter(Boolean)) //=> [ 'this-is', 'my', 'example' ]
```

Alternatively, you could replace between the `+` characters and then match your words.

```
var s = 'this-is my + crappy + example',
    r = s.replace(/\+[^+]*\+/g, '').match(/[\w-]+/g)

console.log(r) //=> [ 'this-is', 'my', 'example' ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you even put the js code to run it! That's perfect

Comment: Thanks for all those additional information. Just accepted your answer for the more in depth explanations.

Answer (score 1):

As per desired output. Get the matched group from index 1.

```
([\w-]+)|\+\s\w+\s\+
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/6)

```
MATCH 1    this-is
MATCH 2    my
MATCH 3    example
```

Comment: You welcome and I think you don't want to do it in two steps. first replace then match.

Comment: read more [JavaScript RegExp Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: Already done, but I was looking in a too complicate direction with the use of a negative lookhead. The solution seems so obvious when you see it ;). Well, I'm not really a regex Ninja a bit more practice will probably help me out!

Comment: you can get the code from the demo. click on code generator tab.